# Retrieving data from a .netCore API via angular

Tags: javascript

Everywthing works and thre sult I get is

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Jeffreys Bay",
            "ProvinceID": 1,
            "Longitude": 24.91667,
            "Latitude": -34.03333
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "Heidelberg",
            "ProvinceID": 3,
            "Longitude": 28.38418,
            "Latitude": -26.491
        },
        {
            "Id": 3,
            "Name": "Springs",
            "ProvinceID": 3,
            "Longitude": 28.44278,
            "Latitude": -26.25472
        },
        {
            "Id": 4,
            "Name": "Boksburg",
            "ProvinceID": 3,
            "Longitude": 28.24097,
            "Latitude": -26.23259
        },
        {
            "Id": 5,
            "Name": "Benoni",
            "ProvinceID": 3,
            "Longitude": 28.32078,
            "Latitude": -26.18848
        },
        {
            "Id": 6,
            "Name": "Kempton Park",
            "ProvinceID": 3,
            "Longitude": 28.23333,
            "Latitude": -26.1
        },
        {
            "Id": 7,
            "Name": "Bedford View",
            "ProvinceID": 3,
            "Longitude": 28.13275,
            "Latitude": -26.17169
        },
        {
            "Id": 8,
            "Name": "Germiston",
            "ProvinceID": 3,
            "Longitude": 28.17078,
            "Latitude": -26.22587
        },
        {
            "Id": 9,
            "Name": "Edenvale",
            "ProvinceID": 3,
            "Longitude": 28.15247,
            "Latitude": -26.14095
        },
        {
            "Id": 10,
            "Name": "Krugersdorp",
            "ProvinceID": 3,
            "Longitude": 27.77515,
            "Latitude": -26.08577
        },
        {
            "Id": 11,
            "Name": "Randfontein",
            "ProvinceID": 3,
            "Longitude": 27.67869,
            "Latitude": -26.19915
        },
        {
            "Id": 12,
            "Name": "Roodepoort",
            "ProvinceID": 3,
            "Longitude": 27.90146,
            "Latitude": -26.12013
        },
        {
            "Id": 13,
            "Name": "Ruimsig",
            "ProvinceID": 3,
            "Longitude": 27.86338,
            "Latitude": -26.082
        },
        {
            "Id": 14,
            "Name": "Weltevreden Park",
            "ProvinceID": 3,
            "Longitude": 27.93076,
            "Latitude": -26.11942
        },
        {
            "Id": 15,
            "Name": "Florida",
            "ProvinceID": 3,
            "Longitude": 27.923,
            "Latitude": -26.175
        },
        {
            "Id": 16,
            "Name": "Randburg",
            "ProvinceID": 3,
            "Longitude": 28.00639,
            "Latitude": -26.09361
        },
        {
            "Id": 17,
            "Name": "Hondeydew",
            "ProvinceID": 3,
            "Longitude": 27.92563,
            "Latitude": -26.07915
        },
        {
            "Id": 18,
            "Name": "Sandton",
            "ProvinceID": 3,
            "Longitude": 28.0567,
            "Latitude": -26.10757
        },
        {
            "Id": 19,
            "Name": "Rivonia",
            "ProvinceID": 3,
            "Longitude": 28.05557,
            "Latitude": -26.04314
        },
        {
            "Id": 31,
            "Name": "Test 1 area",
            "ProvinceID": 1,
            "Longitude": 1,
            "Latitude": 1
        },
        {
            "Id": 32,
            "Name": "Test 2 area",
            "ProvinceID": 2,
            "Longitude": 2,
            "Latitude": 2
        },
        {
            "Id": 33,
            "Name": "Test Changed",
            "ProvinceID": 8,
            "Longitude": 0,
            "Latitude": 0
        },
        {
            "Id": 34,
            "Name": "Toets 2",
            "ProvinceID": 3,
            "Longitude": 0,
            "Latitude": 0
        },
        {
            "Id": 35,
            "Name": "Test2",
            "ProvinceID": 8,
            "Longitude": 0,
            "Latitude": 0
        },
        {
            "Id": 36,
            "Name": "Test3",
            "ProvinceID": 8,
            "Longitude": 0,
            "Latitude": 0
        },
        {
            "Id": 37,
            "Name": "Test4",
            "ProvinceID": 1,
            "Longitude": 0,
            "Latitude": 0
        },
        {
            "Id": 38,
            "Name": "Durban",
            "ProvinceID": 4,
            "Longitude": 31.05,
            "Latitude": -29.88333
        },
        {
            "Id": 39,
            "Name": "Test 4changed",
            "ProvinceID": 8,
            "Longitude": 0,
            "Latitude": 0
        },
        {
            "Id": 40,
            "Name": "New Area",
            "ProvinceID": 8,
            "Longitude": 0,
            "Latitude": 0
        },
        {
            "Id": 41,
            "Name": "Test plus",
            "ProvinceID": 2,
            "Longitude": 0,
            "Latitude": 0
        }
    ],
    "totalCount": -1,
    "groupCount": -1,
    "summary": null
}
```

So all good. However this is where I get lost. Basically I want to use the data array in a an ionic dropdown but as this is an abject I cant get pas this step. I am used to work work with jason so I can accss any item but evry solution I look for is different and to be honest make me more confused. Unfortunately I am a Civil Engineer by education so sometimes struggle with new methods. I apprciate any help. I am convinced I am missing somthing obvious but ....

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add HTML and JavaScript to your question.